# Sudoers for one day per week?

Tags: permissions, security, sudo

I have been volunteered by my boss to be the sysadmin for our production redhat server.
He asked me to tighten the security to avoid mishaps like `rm -f *` that occured not long ago.

Right now, we have 53 users sudo-ing into the machine and it is an audit nightmare. I am wondering if it possible to allow user access only on specific days of the week.

For example, can I have user 'Joe' allowed to login on Tuesdays and Thursdays ONLY and 'Jane' only on Sundays? Can `etc/sudoers` be customized to allow this?

Is there a better way instead of using sudoers?

Comment: I would recommend NOT reading the manual page. See xkcd #1343

Comment: @user60684 Is there a particular part of the manual page that you think OP has failed to read?

Comment: @user60684 I just read through my copy of the man page, and can't find anything obvious that the OP missed...

Comment: No, I am telling him to not read the manual because it is impossible to read IMHO. The OP would probably find an answer in the man page if it was easier to read.

Comment: @user60684 Ahh... :)

Comment: Disclaimer: OP here. I read the man page. And very little made sense. I find more useful info here (no, I am not a sysadmin).

Comment: You can do this, but keep in mind that users can just give themselves back all-the-time sudo access on whatever day they have root.

Comment: Thanks for my morning laughter.  53 sudo users!  I feel better already.

Comment: @Mark0978 if you knew the name of the company, you would probably die laughing your head off. It is a disgrace that it is permitted...on a production server.

Comment: @Chris is the name DirecTV? That's your website and you live close to them...

Comment: This seems kind of silly. It just means Bill will have to wait for his Wednesday morning time slot to run `rm -rf /`.

Comment: @kundor +1 because it's always worth remembering that root can undo restrictions on itself

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`sudo` does its authentication through PAM, like pretty much everything else on a Linux box.

So you should be able to use `pam_time.so` to do this.

By default on Debian at least, that module isn't enabled. You need to add a line that looks like this:

```
account    requisite  pam_time.so
```

to either `/etc/pam.d/sudo` to enable for only sudo or to `/etc/pam.d/common-account` (after the pam-auth-update block) to enable for all programs on the system.

Then edit `/etc/security/time.conf` to set your restrictions. The service name should be `sudo`. For example, to allow Fred to use `sudo` only between 3pm and 5pm on Friday:

```
sudo;*;fred;Fr1500-1700
```

(NOTE: I have not tested this.)

**edit:** To be clear, I agree with the other answer and the various commenters, you appear to have too many people running too many commands as root, and you really need to fix that. And of course if they can become root, they can edit the pam config...

Comment: PAM seems complex to implement but also permits tighter control on who does what and when. Accepted and voted up. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think encouraging him is the right answer, IMAO the correct answer to this question is "RUN FOR THE HILLS!!!!1!1!!1!1"

Comment: Does this actually work?  I am able to control various login mechanisms such as "login", "ssh", "gdm", "su" using pam_time.so, but it's not working for sudo.  I want to prevent anyone becoming root by any normal mechanism outside of office hours.  (I realize it's not bulletproof, someone could prepare an setuid shell or backdoor in advance, but I don't expect that will happen in this situation.)

Answer (score 20):

I would question why 53 users need sudo to do their day to day work -- for most users (even developers), sudo should be a rare exception, not such a routine thing that someone would casually run a `sudo rm -rf *` command.

Can you use group permissions (or even more advanced ACL's) to give people access to the files they need to get their work done, perhaps with some setuid or sudo'ed scripts or binaries to let them do things like restart services? (note that it's hard to write a secure setuid/sudo script, so it's more to keep honest people honest).

Even if you can restrict people to one day a week of sudo access, that's still 53 people with sudo access in a week's time, so it doesn't really help with your core problem.

For that matter, I'd question whether that many users need access to a production server at all -- can you ship logs or whatever data/files they need to a non-production machine?

Comment: Or can you publish some kind of access to the log files they might need, a chroot jailed sftp kind of setup.

Comment: @Johnny the majority of the work done on this host is creating/editing and running shell scripts. Users should not be allowed to `vi/cp/mv/rm`. Only `cd` and `more`. Nothing else.

Comment: @Johnny If I set an ACL on a directory, are the files within that directory inheriting the ACL's attributes by default?

Comment: @Chris Yes, if you set the Default ACL for the directory.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.  Regardless of whether the OP's scenario is sensible, other people have a similar need to lock down "sudo" for some users at certain times.

Comment: @SamWatkins - sometimes the right answer to a question is "You can't do what you want even if you can do something that looks like it does".

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way would be to use the sudoers.d directory (via includedir) for your configuration.  You could then have cron jobs that could place the rules for each user in to that directory for the times you desire.

The #includedir directive can be used in /etc/sudoers to create a sudoers.d directory that you can drop sudoers rules into as part of your rules. For example, given:

```
#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

sudo will read each file in /etc/sudoers.d, skipping file names that end in ‘~’ or contain a ‘.’ character to avoid causing problems with package manager or editor temporary/backup files. Files are parsed in sorted lexical order. That is, /etc/sudoers.d/01_first will be parsed before /etc/sudoers.d/10_second. Be aware that because the sorting is lexical, not numeric, /etc/sudoers.d/1_whoops would be loaded after /etc/sudoers.d/10_second. Using a consistent number of leading zeroes in the file names can be used to avoid such problems.

Note that unlike files included via #include, visudo will not edit the files in a #includedir directory unless one of them contains a syntax error. It is still possible to run visudo with the ‑f flag to edit the files directly.

/etc/sudoers.d/joe would be present when you want joe to have access and you could simply remove the file to take away access.

Comment: I had a problem with my user specific sudoers files: 'sudoers.user1' etc. You remark about the '~' and '.' characters solved my problem. I am so glad you did read the manual! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a crontab to put a users in a sudo group, and then a second crontab to take that user out.